# Scripting and Windows Media Player window

Tags: windows-media-player, vbscript

I have been using Applescript to control playback of Quicktime Player under OSX and are now trying to do the same on Windows 7 and Windows Media Player **window**.

All I need to do is,

- Launch WMP and load audio file
- Toggle playback
- Skip forward or backwards x number of seconds.
- Get its position in the audio file.
- Jump playback to any position I choose.
- Sub-Second positioning. (See EDIT below)

The SDK at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) site seems to offer all that I need but my code below doesn't work.

```
Set oWmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Launches WMP window    
oWmp.openPlayer("F:\2014-04-27.mp3")

' This launches background process, don't want this...
'oWmp.url = "file:///F:/2014-04-27.mp3"

' Wait for file to load...
wscript.sleep 200

' Check the state of the player...
While oWmp.Playstate <> 3
    log "Waiting for player. Current state is: " & oWmp.Playstate
    WScript.Sleep 100 
Wend

oWmp.controls.pause()

wscript.sleep 2000

oWmp.controls.play()
```

The only thing that does work is `openPlayer` statement. Everything else executes but does not error or do anything. Playstate is always 0, even when I go to the WMP window and click on pause/play or stop. I am working on Windows 7 32bit with WMP12

**I do not want to play audio in the background. I want to control playback in WMP window. Using `.url = ...` then the code works. This is running in the background though. See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=133302.0) for more.**

Is the above at all with WMP? I'm happy to use VBS or JScript.

---

EDIT: After some more research, I found that Apple's iTunes has a decent scripting interface and it can do all that I listed above. But upon testing it I remembered that I need sub second positioning which iTunes COM interface does not provide... :(

Comment: Yes, the WMPlayer.OCX object is for scripting WMP. What's the output of your script and where exactly is it failing?

Comment: @TimDeBaets The only thing that does work is `openPlayer` statement. Everything else executes but does not error or do anything. I working on Windows7 with WMP12. Playstate is always 0, even when I go to the WMP window and click on pause/play or stop.

Comment: I've edited my question and it appears the code will work only for the WMP object in the background. It does NOT work for the WMP window. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openPlayer` starts *another* instance of WMP, in full mode. All the other WMP calls in your script only affect the internal instance of WMP that was created by your call to `CreateObject`. That internal instance is invisible in this case, but can also be visible, like when the WMP control is embedded in a web page.

Interacting with the full mode WMP is called "remoting", see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564264(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info. But I'm afraid that it's not possible to do this from a script. You will need to write a special program in a language like C++.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Tim answered the question as posted, I want to add this answer for future reference to anyone else trying to do the same thing.

As I mentioned, in my question's edit, Quicktime Player for Windows was close but not quite. So I kept searching and found a [scripting plugin](http://www.pretentiousname.com/gen_scripting/) for the venerable old WinAmp audio player and it works great! I get millisecond positioning and everything else I need.

Only minor issue with it is that it's 32bit and running it in an Windows x64 environment means that I have to remember to use the right VBS engine, which is no big deal.